# Android GCM- Register Id and Project Id

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I can't get register id with my project id

Can i get new project id with different `google` account for same project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### follow the steps below:

1. launch your application
2. check if register-id
3. if register id is empty string then check for any error messages in ddms
4. if there is no error messages then
   a) Check whether senderid is correct.
   b) Check your manifest permissions
5. if there are error messages then can you paste it here?

genereally what happens when application launches first time it take some time to generate the register id and register id can be catch in onRegister() method in GCMIntentService class.

Comment: hi, i put GCMIntentService class in main package and it works now. Does GCMIntentService only work in main package?

Comment: yes, GCMIntentService class should be in the main package and dont change the name of the class it should be GCMIntentService only.